# Finite State Machines

Tags: computer-science, mips, state-machine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpxyD.png

I am learning about finite state machines using MIPS. I was given this diagram linked above and told that it currently supports add, sub, slt, and, or lw, sw, beq, & j. I was asked to write any new signals, states, or transitions needed to implement the instruction nor

I know nor in MIPS is an R-type instruction, because R-type instructions are already implemented in this FSM doesn't that mean that nor is already a supported instruction and nothing needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Be certain you understand whether your assignment refers to the *logical operation* NOR or the *assembly-language instruction* `nor`.  If it means the logical operator, then you'll have to think about the different forms of NOR:

Example:

```
nor  t0, t2, t3    ; R-type nor

nori t0, t2, 0x4A  ; I-type nor
```

See [this page](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/spimsal/talref.html) for more information about instruction types.